# Knockout viewmodel returning function (how to?)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, require

I have an application that displays messages from a database. Using Breeze.js for serverside API controller and Knockout.js for databinding.

Initially we get 30 messages and from then every 30 second we get the latest messages that were inserted in the database.

```
    function messageViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var refreshRate = 5000;
    var lastMessageID = null;
    self.allMessages = ko.observableArray();

    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Messages').orderByDesc('Id').expand('Poster').take(20);
    manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(function(messages) {
            self.allMessages(messages.results);
            lastMessageID = messages.results[0].Id();
            window.setInterval(refresh, refreshRate);
        }).fail(function(error) {
            alert(error.message);
        });

   function refresh() {
        query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Messages').orderByDesc('Id').where('Id', '>', lastMessageID).expand('Poster');
        manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (newMessages) {
                if (newMessages.results.length != 0) {
                    for (var count = 0; count < newMessages.results.length; count++) {
                        self.allMessages.unshift(newMessages.results[count]);
                        lastMessageID = newMessages.results[0].Id();
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function (error) {
                alert(error.name+" "+error.message);
            });
    }
}

return {
    getPosterByCallsign: getPosterByCallsign,
    MessageViewModel: messageViewModel,
    postMessage: postMessage,
}
```

I  would now like to be able to call the refresh method from another js module. How can i achive this? The viewmodel is called from an module like this:

```
define(["common/dataService"], function(n0uk) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new n0uk.MessageViewModel());

    $('#postButton').click(function() {
        n0uk.postMessage(window.message);
    });
    $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            n0uk.postMessage(window.message);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

});

The refresk should be called after the n0uk.postMessage() call....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [PubSub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS).
Subscribe in your first module:

```
PubSub.subscribe('refreshMessages', refresh);
```

and publish in your second module whenever needed:

```
PubSub.publish('refreshMessages');
```

Comment: My problem is that i can't call/execute the refresh function from outside the ViewModel function. I would like to have a solution like messageViewModel.Refresh() that can be called. The update of UI works fine, new messages are displayed as the are inserted in the self.allMessages observable array, thats not the issue.

Comment: PubSub is designed for exactly what you're describing, did you look into it? Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: PubSun turned out to be the perfect answer indeed! Thanks for hinting me in the good direction...